# Why can't java.util.Scanner see 0700 as a octal literal?

Tags: java, octal

```
   public static void main(String argv[]){
         String a="0700";
         Scanner s = new Scanner(a);
         while(s.hasNextLong()){
              System.out.print(s.nextLong()+",");
         }
```

Result will be "700," not the "448".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default the scanner assumes that the number is in base 10 and will ignore the leading 0s. You can specify another radix if you want - the code below prints 448:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a = "0700";
    Scanner s = new Scanner(a);
    while (s.hasNextLong(8)) { //make sure the number can be parsed as an octal
        System.out.print(s.nextLong(8)); //read as an octal value
    }
}
```

Comment: s.hasNextLong() -> s.hasNextLong(8)

Comment: not really, just for consistency, it will work without radix too i think

Comment: @EddieJamsession The best way to close the question is to [accept one of the answers](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can set default radix using `Scanner#useRadix(radix)` method or pass radix explicitly to `Scanner#hasNextLong(radix)` and `Scanner#nextLong(radix)` methods.

Answer (score 0):

Read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLong%28%29). It says that it will use the default radix of the Scanner. If the default is not acceptable then you can change it with the `useRadix(int radix)` method or use the `nextLong(int radix)` for a temporary change in radix.